# How to upload huge JSON file into Snowflake table?

Tags: json, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bigdata, snowflake-stage

There is a "big.json" of about 70 GB, which is a single object {}. The main part of the file, 99.99999999% is stored in "body".

Can you tell me how to load this file into a temporary Snowflake table or just a Snowflake table? And how to do it as fast as possible?

Tried to use ijson library to iteratively read and split into smaller json files.

Also don't understand what the table structure should be. As JSON contains nested structures. Basically, such a file only contains information about one company.

There was an idea to split and convert to CSV or JSON form and implement parallel loading, but how to do it.

I would be very grateful if anyone could advise how this could be implemented.

Example of JSON-file structure below.

```
{
    "entity_name": "Cars",
    "entity_type": "Manual",
    "last_updated_on": "2023-04-01",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "model_name": null,
    "model_id_type": null,
    "model_id": null,
    "model_market_type": null,
    "provider_references": null,
    "body": [{
                "negotiation_arrangement": "bundle",
                "name": "Narrative not found",
                "billing_code_type": "CPT",
                "billing_code_type_version": "2022",
                "billing_code": "Y3600",
                "description": "Narrative not found",
                "negotiated_rates": [{
                        "provider_groups": [{
                            "npi": [
                                1083010953
                            ],
                            "tin": {
                                "type": "ein",
                                "value": "47-1161992"
                            }
                        }],
                        "negotiated_prices": [{
                            "negotiated_type": "derived",
                            "negotiated_rate": 100.02,
                            "expiration_date": "9999-12-31",
                            "service_code": [
                                "19",
                                "22",
                                "23"
                            ],
                            "billing_class": "institutional"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "provider_groups": [{
                            "npi": [
                                1962402354
                            ],
                            "tin": {
                                "type": "ein",
                                "value": "13-4257646"
                            }
                        }],
                        "negotiated_prices": [{
                            "negotiated_type": "derived",
                            "negotiated_rate": 100.09,
                            "expiration_date": "9999-12-31",
                            "service_code": [
                                "19",
                                "22",
                                "23"
                            ],
                            "billing_class": "institutional"
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            }
]}
```

Comment: Irrespective of the tools used, is there a pattern from which the JSON file can be split in smaller files? If there isn't then I don't see a lot of options. JSON in Snowflake is stored under a VARIANT data type column and is subject to a limit of 16MB per row, so if you can't split the file then I don't see a lot of options here.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really one big record then the only solution (I can think of) would be to insert individual parts of the JSON into appropriate target tables - either as chunks of JSON data inserted into variant fields for subsequent processing or as individual fields. For example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (ID, varchar1, variant1)
    SELECT t.$1, t.$2, t.$2 FROM @mystage1 (file_format => 'myformat', pattern=>'.*data.*[.]csv.gz') t;
```